# SendInput to background window

Tags: c++, winapi, sdl, sendinput, directinput

I want to send the mouse and keyboard input, which is recieved from android client, to games running on windows.
`SendInput` works for almost all games I have worked so far. But for `SendInput` to work the game must be a foreground window.

To solve that I used `PostMessage(hwnd,...)` with hwnd being handle to the game window. But this does not work if game is using DirectInput. That was solved by hooking `GetDeviceState`. Now another game I started working on is using `WM_INPUT` or raw input and I have to create raw input to make it work.

According to this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> DirectInput is a set of API calls that abstracts input devices on the
>   system. Internally, DirectInput creates a second thread to read
>   WM_INPUT data, and using the DirectInput APIs will add more overhead
>   than simply reading WM_INPUT directly.

directInput works using WM_INPUT.

> The [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function inserts the events in the INPUT structures
>   serially into the keyboard or mouse input stream. These events are not
>   interspersed with other keyboard or mouse input events inserted either
>   by the user (with the keyboard or mouse) or by calls to keybd_event,
>   mouse_event, or other calls to SendInput.

So SendInput is also providing abstraction.

All I want is to send the input to application independently even when its window is not in focus. That way I will be able to send input to multiple games at once. Is there any way to achieve this using one higher level API call like SendInput? Can this be done with SendInput? Is there any C/C++ library for that?

Comment: Games do a lot to try and prevent this, for obvious reasons. I'd consider using an arduino board to mimic a keyboard.

Comment: @Matt SendInput alone works fine with only drawback that it works on the focused window only.

Comment: DirectInput and SendInput are, despite the names, very different things.

Comment: See ["You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513), and ["When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have read related posts on that blog. In all posts he criticized trying to send input to an application the wrong way (e.g. PostMessage) but never actually suggested how [Michal Zygmunt](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101221-00/?p=11953/) should actually solve his problem?

Answer (score 5):

When registering your input device using the `RAWINPUTDEVICE` structure,
set `dwFlags = RIDEV_EXINPUTSINK` to receive input when the process is in the background.

Example:

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE rid;

rid.usUsagePage = 1;
rid.usUsage     = 4;    // Joystick
rid.dwFlags     = RIDEV_EXINPUTSINK;
rid.hwndTarget  = window;

if (!RegisterRawInputDevices(&rid, 1, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE)))
    return -1;
```

Comment: And How To Write data to the device ? SendInput with RAWINPUT ?